# Simple CSS background not displaying

Tags: css

I'm working on a simple webdesign assignment and have hit a bump. I'm trying to get a background image to repeat vertically, but there's one small problem: the image isn't showing up. It's in the same directory and the code is, as far as I can tell, (cross-checking it against W3 schools, primarily) correct. I welcome any ideas.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    body
    {
    background-image:url('VerticalTileJPEG.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>Have some text!</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is the image name correct? Remember it's case sensitive.

Comment: UPDATE: Tried tiling regularly on a new document and it's working fine. Still not sure what's gone wrong with this one.

Comment: What's the width/height of your image?

Comment: It's supposed to be vertically repeating, so the professor had us creating it at 1X1024.

Comment: So you have an image with `1x1024` dimension, so you must repeat it on x-axis: `background-repeat:repeat-x;`.

Comment: Just tried, still no luck; thank you, though, for correcting my axis issue!

Answer (score 1):

That will only work if the image file is in the same folder as the page calling it. If it's in an images folder, for example, the path would have to be something like:

```
background-image:url('images/VerticalTileJPEG.jpg');
```

If that doesn't help, post some more info. Also make sure to use a doctype.

EDIT: If you are sure that the path to the image is correct, and that the file name is correct (including capitals), then perhaps try a shorthand background declaration:

```
background:url(images/VerticalTileJPEG.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
```

To check that you have the path right, go to your web inspector (e.g. Chrome> [right click] Inspect Element and then click on the image url in the right (CSS) column. You will see right away if the browser is finding the image or not.

Comment: Moved the file and updated the doctype, but still no luck. Have tried the file as JPEG and GIF, with no change. Image name is correct as it was automatically popped in via Adobe Dreamweaver.

Comment: Yeah, the file type won't be the issue. I suspect it's still a path issue, but anyhow, I've updated my post with some extra suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to repeat up and down (vertically along the y axis), but your body is only 1 paragraph tall which (I presume) is not tall enough to show the image more than once.

To repeat it vertically, you need more content down the page or set your background on the html element not the body.

To repeat it horizontally, repeat-x.

Comment: Setting a background for `body` doesn't need the content to show.

Answer (score 0):

Use Doctype in your page and make sure that the image you want in the background is in the same folder in which u have HTML files or if it is in another folder in that directory than try this code.
**background-image:url('/foldername/picturename.pictureextension');**

for example if the image name is "xyz.jpg" and it is in folder naming "images" then the code will be:
**background-image:url('/images/xyz.jpg');**

Comment: Added the doctype and made sure it was in the same folder. Tried the code, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

*(From comments)*

> **NOX** What's the width/height of your image?
>   **YOU** It's supposed to be vertically repeating, so the professor had us creating it at **1X1024**.

So you must repeat the image on the x-axis:

```
body {
    background-image: url('VerticalTileJPEG.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

---

#### Some Notes

- Make sure your file name is exactly `VerticalTileJPEG.jpg` (case-sensitive).
- Make sure your HTML file and image, are in the same folder.